# Schema hasn't been registered for model "User". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: mongoose, production-environment, nuxtjs3

I run my Nuxt3 application in development environment and it's working normally but when I build the project I get the error message 'Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)' . I find out it is happening only in those pages that I have a request that contains populate method in server/api/ files. But I don't know why this happen's in production environment and works just fine in development environment.

I just want it work normally as it is working in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

everything was fine.
I changed the module and did a lot of tests finally I got a solution.
It looks like Nuxt3 has a bug in production environment.
When you build your project it doesn't load your schemas and your defined models.

to fix the following error we should make a request to api's of all your models.
you don't need to fetch anything just call that api so the server will load the related schema and the model. this request should be to an api that doesn't use populate function otherwise you will get the same error again.
and it's better to make these requests in the home page of your Nuxt3 application